# How to inclide script available inside node_module folder in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, node-modules

When I am installing a node_module then relevant folder is getting added inside node_module folder of my application. Now I want to include a script which is available in installed module, say ..
installed_module/dist/

So how can I include this script in VueJs project?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the script tag of your .vue file -

```
import Module from 'module'
```